# video file not supported message not showing

Tags: video

I currently have a video file which is not supported by safari and have entered a message to explain that the browser does not support the file type . However the message is not visible . any ideas on how to remedy this

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" poster="/imgs/vfx-reel.png" controls>
        <source src="media/reel-animation.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        apologies but your browser does not support the video file type . video can currently be viewed in chrome and firefox . we are working to remedy this
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

That text would be shown if a browser does not support the video element, not when the video element has nothing to play.

There's an example of how to catch this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Error_handling) by capturing an error event on the source element:

```
var v = document.querySelector('video'),
  sources = v.querySelectorAll('source'),
  lastsource = sources[sources.length-1];
lastsource.addEventListener('error', function(ev) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerHTML = v.innerHTML;
  v.parentNode.replaceChild(d, v);
}, false);
```